# How to disable/hide CPack and Workflow buttons in VSCode CMake Tools extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

After VSCode and CMake Tools extension update, there are 3 more buttons in the status bar: CTest, Run CPack, Run Workflow

I don't use those options and have only found how to hide CTest in the settings.

How do I disable or hide the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `settings.json` and add those lines. This helped me.

```
    "cmake.options.advanced": {
        "cpack": {
            "statusBarVisibility": "visible"
        },
        "workflow": {
            "statusBarVisibility": "visible"
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can also add `"ctest": {"statusBarVisibility": "hidden"}` to the `"cmake.options.advanced"` section in `settings.json` to hide CTest button